# Generating Distinct ID based on column values in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have around 160 distinct team_names and i am trying to generate randon 4 digit ID for each of the unique team_name

```
 team_names

     Hyd
     Mum
     Hyd
     Che
     Pun
     USA
     UK
     LON 
     ---
     ---
     so on ...
```

Output will be something like this

```
    team_name     ID

     Hyd        9901
     Mum        9902
     Hyd        9901
     Che        9904
     Pun        9906
     USA        9908
     UK         9976
     LON        9963
```

and so on. For each unique team there should be unique 4 digit ID

Comment: Why random? Why four digits?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe that is how database is designed fro taxonomy. So trying to get random 4 digit number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dense_rank()` and arithmetic:

```
select team_name,
       9800 + dense_rank() over (order by team_name)
from t;
```

For any table that has all the teams, this will produce the same results.